# Bash script fails where command line works

Tags: bash, bash-expansion

I wrote a basic bash function to test for the occurence of a string search argument in another string. Running it from the command line gives expected results. Running the same from a shell script fails. Can somebody show me the errors of my ways?

```
me@mylaptop $ line='someidentifier 123                     another identifier 789 065             theend'
me@mylaptop $ sarg='+([0-9])+([ ])another identifier'
me@mylaptop $ type strstr
strstr is a function
strstr ()
{
   [ "${1#*$2*}" = "$1" ] && return 1;
   return 0
}
me@mylaptop $ strstr "$line" "$sarg" ; echo "$?"
0
me@mylaptop $
```

My script:

```
me@mylaptop $ cat l.sh
#!/bin/bash

function strstr ()
{
   [ "${1#*$2*}" = "$1" ] && return 1;
   return 0
}

line='someidentifier 123                     another identifier 789 065             theend'
sarg='+([0-9])+([ ])another identifier'

echo '==='"$line"'==='

echo '==='"$sarg"'==='

strstr "$line" "$sarg"

echo "$?"

me@mylaptop $ ./l.sh
===someidentifier 123                     another identifier 789 065             theend===
===+([0-9])+([ ])another identifier===
1
me@mylaptop $
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have enabled the `extglob` shell option in your interactive shell, but not in your script:

```
$ strstr "$line" "$sarg" ; echo "$?"
1
$ shopt -s extglob
$ strstr "$line" "$sarg" ; echo "$?"
0
```

Note that your function could be simplified into

```
strstr () {
    [ "${1#*$2*}" != "$1" ]
}
```

Comment: Correct. Perfect. Thanks. Both for the solution and the improvement.